# Get matching string from list after comparing element from pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to check Pandas DataFrame column contains keyword elements in a List object. If column contains that keyword from List object, then I want to populate that List Element in a new column of a DataFrame itself.

```
L = ['abc','pqr','xyz']
```

If DataFrame is

```
Col1      Col2
'abc xyz' 
'pqr lmn'
```

I want to compare DF with L and when 'abc xyz' contains element of L (i.e. 'abc'), then I want to populate 'abc' in Col2.

Could you pls help me to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: And what does your expected output look like?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
import pandas as pd

L = ['abc','pqr','xyz']
df = pd.DataFrame(['abc xyz', 'pqr lmn'], columns=['Col1'])

df['Col2'] = df['Col1'].str.findall('|'.join(L)).apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```

gives:

```
>>> df
      Col1     Col2
0  abc xyz  abc xyz
1  pqr lmn      pqr
```

[EDIT]

if you want just the first matching keyword:

```
df['Col2'] = df['Col1'].str.findall('|'.join(L)).str[0]
```

gives:

```
>>> df
      Col1 Col2
0  abc xyz  abc
1  pqr lmn  pqr
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But I just want to populate Col2 with First matching keyword from the list (do not want to join multiple keywords). Can you pls let me know what changes to be done in above code? Thanks!

Comment: see the edit I just made

Comment: no problem! you can thank me even more by accepting the answer :)